# smtp over curl?

Tags: curl

I tried to use this [example](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-smtp.html) to send email to my smtp account at gmail. I know that, in order to use the gmail smtp server, you usually need a valid username/password combination, but other smtp servers (e.g. hotmail) need to be able to send mail to gmail and they have no knowledge of passwords. My question is, is it possible to send mail to a gmail account without knowing the gmail password. The error code was:

```
curl: (55) MAIL failed: 530
```

Comment: This is not a question about Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Note that some SMTP servers support authentication by IP address, if the same IP recently authenticated with the corresponding POP server.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev all will readily accept mail to users in their domain, even from president@whitehouse.gov

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is not a mailserver (or [message transfer agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)). To my understanding it acts as an mail user agent (MUA) - "email client" - and it rather connects to a mailserver to hand over your mail to the SMPT server which then sends it to the recipients MTA (via relays if necessary). Or as the [example](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-smtp.html) you have linked puts it:

> curl supports sending data to a an SMTP server, which combined with the right set of command line options makes an email get sent to a set of receivers of your choice.

An SMTP server may choose to not deliver your outbound mail unless you [authenticate yourself as a legimitate client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Outgoing_mail_server_access_restrictions) to prevent spam and other abuse of the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, just not over the usual `smtp.gmail.com` server. What I did was an MX lookup on `gmail.com` and you get a slew of servers, I picked this one:

```
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

and the security there is rather more lax, no need for TLS/SSL and no need for a password.

Comment: This will likely only work if your destination is a gmail.com address. And I suspect there are strong anti-spam measures on those servers so I wouldn't be surprised if even email to gmail.com address are sometimes rejected.

Comment: I'm just happy the email shows up, even if in spam.

Comment: Don't forget to check the exit code from the curl command to ensure it successfully submitted the message.

Comment: No need, since I sent the message to myself and received it.